# Java program compiling error

Tags: java

i dont know what im doing wrong but the compiler keeps saying:

> StringLength.java:3: error: class problem is public, should be declared in a file named problem.java public class problem

here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String s = input.nextLine();

    String lower = "";
    String total = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char thisChar = s.charAt(i);

        if (thisChar >= 97 && thisChar <= 122) {
            lower += thisChar;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total amount of characters: " + s.length() + " - " + s);
    System.out.println("Lower case letters: " + lower.length() + " - " + lower);
    }
}
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: thanks that was very helpfull

Comment: if some answer helps you, [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). No need to post a thanks comment

Answer (score 4):

Your file is named `StringLength.java` but your class is named `problem` on Line 3. Your class name should have the same name as your file name, without the .java extension, i.e. `StringLength`.

Answer (score 1):

when you type like `java StringLength`, jvm will try to find main method in that class and  that class has to be public. In this case your class name in which main method exists and class name given in the command is different. 
Either you should change your file name to `problem.java` or change your class name to `StringLength`

Answer (score 0):

```
char thisChar = s.charAt(i);
```

charAt() returns character at the index specified
but you are checking
    if (thisChar >= 97 && thisChar <= 122)

Are you checking for ascii value?? if so please correct your code. Example follows.

```
char thisChar = s.charAt(i);
int thisAscii = String.valueOf(thisChar).codePointAt(0);
if (thisAscii >= 97 && thisAscii <= 122) {

}
```